# Unity C# Instantiate particle effects with correct rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, euler-angles

While building some turrets in Unity I noticed that all my bullets were flying off in one direction, and not the one I was aiming for!

I looked online for help, but the Quaternion.Euler doesn't seem to cut it for me.
Am I doing something wrong?
(Probably, but I could use help figuring out what)

```
void Update()
{
            if(canShoot == true)
            {
                StartCoroutine(FireGun());
            }
}

IEnumerator FireGun()
{
    canShoot = false;

    var newBullet = Instantiate(bullet, gun.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, gun.rotation.y, 0));

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    canShoot = true;
}
```

Much obliged!

Comment: What direction do you want your bullets to go in (based on your gun's `transform`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your bullet to have the same rotation as your gun, just apply the gun's rotation to the bullet.

```
Instantiate(bullet, gun.transform.position, gun.transform.rotation);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @BenRubin For some reason, I kept getting errors when I first tried such a thing, but it must have been a mixup between vector3 and .rotate stuff. Its hard to recall haha!

Answer (score 1):

If your camera is pointing at what you want to shoot, you could take the quaternion from that and apply it to the bullet.

If not, you could try to take the rotation of the turret and apply it to the bullets.

Comment: Thank you @TheChubbyPanda, for some reason my first attempt of doing that didnt work out, but probably because I was trying to cram the rotation as an vector3 into the euler..